# Flash of Invisible Text

Tags: jquery, fonts, font-face

I have a website, where all the text in it is using custom font. The problem is that each browser behaves differently with the custom font like the Flash of Invisible Text.

Basically, what I want to do is to initially in the document.ready to set the font to Arial, and then once the font is installed, I set all my text to the custom font.

However, here is the result I am getting? Every page is becoming arial then my custom font. I can see the font flashing which is annoying?

Now, my question please is:
- How can I create a jquery event that is called only once through my whole website? thanks,

Comment: *Initially in the document.ready to set the font to Arial, and then once the font is installed, I set all my text to the custom font.* -> *Every page is becoming arial and then my custom font.* What did you expect to happen?

Comment: As I understand it, browsers intentionally went _away_ from this functionality, preferring to not render any text at all for up to 3 seconds while the custom font loads. This was to avoid the Flash of Unstyled Text (FOUT) issue, but also introduced a new one (bug or feature at your discretion: Flash of Invisible Text (FOIT). It sounds like your code is doing exactly what you want it to do: render Arial and then render the custom font. Check this out for some JS on how to `check` that your font has loaded: https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-events.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help.. Now, it is working fine:

I used the following:

1- First, in the CSS I am using Arial

2- Using this JS: // I put the below inside jQuery pagebeforeshow event

```js
WebFontConfig = { google: { families: [ "customfont1","customfont2"] } , active : function() { 
  //alert("this is the default font");
  
   // All Body
   for ( i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++) {
   document.all[i].style.fontFamily = "customfont1";
  }
  // Titles
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("title");
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.fontFamily = "customfont2";
              }
     
 },
 timeout: 2000, 
};

(function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('webfont.js');
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();
 
});
```